# Help with specific curve integral

Tags: calculus

I don't really know where to begin with this integral:

$$\int_D \sqrt{xy} \, dx \, dy$$

with $D$ being the curve with equation $(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{3})^4=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{6}}$

We're not supposed to use the vector calculus tools, just double integrals over rectangles and some very limited general regions, integrals in polar, cylindrical and spherical coordinates and change of variables. I'd guess this requires a very intelligent change of variable, but I'm not really seeing it atm :/

Comment: Your integral is NOT a path integral because $\int_Ddxdy=\text{Area}(D)$

Comment: Do you mean the region **inside** the curve?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I knew it couldn't be a path integral because we're not supposed to use that yet (I don't even know what it is yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Try substituting $x = \sqrt{2}r\cos\theta$ and $y = \sqrt{3}r\sin \theta$.

The bounds for the double integral will look kinda ugly, but if you integrate with respect to $r$ first and remember the Jacobian of the transformation, the resulting single integral (w.r.t. $\theta$) will be easy.

Comment: I.e. after scaling $x$ and $y$ by the appropriate factors, it's polar coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it. The bounds are indeed ugly, but they do give the right answer!